# Does Cartalyst Sentry 2, query database to check permission or check other thing?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am using Cartalyst Sentry 2 for my user managment in my project ( using laravel 4 ). It works good and I like it.

I just have a small question that when you try to check the user permission or check anything about that user like is activated or other.  Does is always send request to database to check it?

I mean if implement my project in such a way that I got to check permission often, then it will be bad that there will be too much of request to the database.

So I wanted to know **Does Sentry store some or most of those properties in cookies?** , so become faster and not too much request to database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it checks everything in database. Cookies would be too dangerous (users can modify their rights)

You can cache data with Cache class in Laravel 4 to compensate too many queries to your database.